# observeEvent() and reactiveValues() - How to create good placeholder

Tags: r, shiny

I create an app where I have two `actionButtons`

```
ui.R
        h4("First | Second "),
        actionButton(inputId = "first", 
                     label = "First"),
        actionButton(inputId = "second", 
                     label = "Second"),
```

Thats my `server.R`

```
#create the datasetbased on the choice of "First" or "Second"
myDataSet <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)


#observer to see what is clicked. Decision is send to "reactiveValues"
observeEvent(input$first, {
        myDataSet$data <- dataframe1
})


#observer to see what is clicked. Decision is send to "reactiveValues"
observeEvent(input$second, {
        myDataSet$data <- dataframe2
})
```

Depending on the input coming from the `actionButton` I want to store `dataframe1` or `dataframe2` in `myDataSet`.
As written here: Is that the way in `reactiveValues()` to create the variable which will be holding my `dataframes`? Note, the extend (columns/rows) of my `dataframes` send in the `observeEvent()` varies.

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you want to achieve. Maybe you can rephrase your question.

Answer (score 2):

here is the entire working example

```
ui <- fluidPage( 
    h4("First | Second "),
    actionButton(inputId = "first", label = "First"),
    actionButton(inputId = "second", label = "Second"),
    htmlOutput("nrows")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    dataframe1 <- data.frame(c(1,2,3))
    dataframe2 <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5))
    #create the datasetbased on the choice of "First" or "Second"
    myDataSet <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)

    #observer to see what is clicked. Decision is send to "reactiveValues"
    observeEvent(input$first, {
            myDataSet$data <- dataframe1
    })

    #observer to see what is clicked. Decision is send to "reactiveValues"
    observeEvent(input$second, {
            myDataSet$data <- dataframe2
    })
    output$nrows <- renderUI({  
            HTML(paste('dataframe rows:', nrow(myDataSet$data)))    
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What is the difference? Looks the same as OP code but with extra code that make it full example.